# How can I make the slider bar to be touchable on iPad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 3 slide bars on my website and I can't move it by finger on iPad. The only way to move it is to tap on places where should to be the next step. On desktop is working properly.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#slider1" ).slider({
      range: "2",
      min: 1,
      max: 2,
      value: 1,
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider1" ).slider( "value" ) );
  });
```

This is the CSS file hope to be helpful

```
.ui-slider {
    position: absolute;
    width:279px;
}
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 1.2em;
    height: 1.4em;
}
.ui-slider .ui-slider-range {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    display: block;
}

.ui-slider-horizontal {
    height: 1em;
}
.ui-widget-content {
    background:url("../images/bar.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.ui-state-default {
    background: url("../images/slidet.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including the TouchPunch library might help.
http://touchpunch.furf.com/

It assists in giving jQuery UI mobile compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

use javascript's touchstart, touchmove, and touchend events. Nothing in CSS will make it respond to touch and since you've not provided any JS, I can't help you more.

I'd recommend finding a carousel that works on multi-touch. This should be easy if you search github for carousel.

Comment: is slide bar why to use carousel?

Answer (score 0):

On the last project I did, TouchPunch conflicted with some of our other script. We ended up using [No UI Slider[1](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/)] instead. It doesn't have any dependencies besides regular jQuery.

Comment: OK, I tried but is not shows up. I used the <script src="../js/jquery.nouislider.min.js"></script> and <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.nouislider.min.css"> followed by `<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#slider1").noUiSlider({
    start: [20, 80],
    connect: true,
    range: {
        'min': 0,
        'max': 100
    }
}
});
</script>`

Comment: Have you checked to make sure all your includes are loading properly? If so, I recommend copying one of the examples from the site and seeing if that works. Are you getting any errors in your Javascript console?